# Sporadic application deadlock in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, task, deadlock

I have an ASP.NET 4.7.2 MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity and the OWIN `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware`. In the `RefreshTokenProvider.OnReceive` method i'm accessing the `SignInManager.CreateUserIdentity` method which is an ASP.NET Identity method that internally uses `AsyncHelper` (see below) to call the asynchronous method. Every so often (typically months apart on a busy system), this breaks down and locks up the entire application. From a memory dump i've gathered, there were 565 threads waiting inside `GetResult`
[image]

```cs
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation, Inc. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
{
    internal static class AsyncHelper
    {
        private static readonly TaskFactory _myTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

        public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
        {
            var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            return _myTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
                return func();
            }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            _myTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
                return func();
            }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

The memory dump showed 580+ Tasks, that were **all** in the `RanToCompletion` state. I was unable to diagnose why `GetResult` does not succeed, given that the Task has completed, nor why that many threads pile up there rapidly when it worked for months before and why the entire app becomes unresponsive, even if they don't exercise this path. This caused a production outage now multiple times and i don't see how to resolve this other than rebooting it.

I've tried to use the `OnReceiveAsync` method but those seem pointless because before they're invoked, there's this little snippet:

```
if (OnReceiveAsync != null && OnReceive == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.Exception_AuthenticationTokenDoesNotProvideSyncMethods);
}
```

## EDIT: Reproduction and explanation of the issue:

The issue can be reproduced by this WebAPI 2 Controller

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication65.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public string Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            return AsyncHelper.RunSync(PostAsync);
        }

        private async Task<string> PostAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

and this program to generate load

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp36
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int x = i;
                var t = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var content = new StringContent("\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\"");
                    content.Headers.ContentType = mediaTypeHeaderValue;
                    await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44371/api/values", content);
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                });
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
            Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

What the program will do, is hit the application with 100 requests in just a few milliseconds. This will lead to all previously free threads being stuck at `AsyncHelper.RunSync` with a lot more requests queued and no response being sent yet at all. The ThreadPool notices that it needs more threads but will add about only one thread per second which will immediately get stuck at `AsyncHelper.RunSync` trying to serve one of the queued requests. About a minute later, when the ThreadPool has expanded by about 100 additional threads to serve the 100 requests, all pending requests will respond in the blink of an eye and the application is responsive again.

The difference on my app is, that requests keep comming in, unlike the sample where only 100 requests are sent at once. This means my app can't recover from this scenario as the ThreadPool does not create new threads fast enough to keep up with incomming requests.

Creating an async copy of my `ReceiveRefreshToken` method and populating `OnReceiveAsync` in addition to `OnReceive` appears to avoid the problem enough to not get exhausted on the ThreadPool.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you should consider reporting to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the application exhausted ThreadPool.

AsyncHelper uses TaskScheduler.Default which means execution on ThreadPool. It should work fine until all threads are blocked (e.g. many users and/or slow response from token endpoint) and there're no more free threads to continue. It would lead to deadlock (you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d)). Since application has only one ThreadPool all stops if it is exhausted.

I would try to use OnReceiveAsync anyway and create user in async way from here. You will likely need a dummy OnReceive in order to avoid exception.

Alternatively you can try to extend size of the ThreadPool but it is only a short term solution not guaranteed to work all the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is it, although the threadpool isn't entirely exhausted, but it appears that my webapp gets hit with a lot of request at once at which point, all threads are busy, and the ThreadPool is adding about one thread per second which isn't enough to keep up. I've managed to reproduce it and added the reproduction to the question